# How can I see a list of recently connected bluetooth devices?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

Is there a way that I can see when a Bluetooth device was last connected to my Windows 10 laptop?

Answer (score 3):

Try the log file `%SystemRoot%\inf\setupapi.dev.log` for connection logs. Or use tools like [BluetoothView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html) or [BluetoothLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_log_view.html) for monitoring Bluetooth devices in the vicinity of your laptop.

There's timestamps and device states (like install, initiate, ...). If you cannot identify the device (should be BTH something for Bluetooth), connect the same device once more and look at the tail of the log to find the device ID.

Comment: How do I decipher what the log says?

Comment: @SuperNinja741DoesGaming try looking in the official documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setupapi-text-logs

Comment: I was looking for a solution how to systematically from a cmd script find the name of a particular bluetooth connection (because it contains a serial number that I need on very many pc's), and this was the only solution I found so far. It works beautifully. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you go in "Devices and printers" and select a paired device, you may be able to find the last connection time there.

Go in the hardware tab, click "Properties", then "Details" and choose the property called "Bluetooth last connected time".

In my case, the time appears to be shifted in the future of two hours, but the minutes are correct.

[image: Device property window]