# How can I check the Bluetooth version of a connected device?

Tags: windows-10, macos, bluetooth

I recently purchased a keyboard that seems to have had a few different iterations on its Bluetooth chip (3, 4, and now 5). I'm trying to determine which version of Bluetooth is supported by the keyboard I received.

My 2018 15" MacBook pro has Bluetooth 5.0. How can I figure out the Bluetooth version of a connected device in either macOS or Windows 10 (via Bootcamp)?

Comment: [How to check Bluetooth version in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-check-bluetooth-version-in-windows-10/)

Comment: That only helps with determining the version of the computer, not the connected device.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is technically the [LMP version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Link_Manager) (Link Manager Protocol version of Bluetooth).

It's not that by using BT 5.0 you will be automatically "low energy" but only if the host (your keyboard) is using it this way. In the [bluetooth stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_protocol_stack) ([picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#/media/File:Bluetooth_protokoly.svg)), the protocols used in the controller are quite different when implementing the [subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_4.0) Classic (BR/EDR), Low Energy (LE), High Speed (HS) (see [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-dev-faq) from Microsoft on transport protocols).

In this sense, in the subset of procotols BT 4.0 for low energy, the link layer one is named LE LL and the radio is quite different than the BT 4.0 Classic, although same frequency.

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-bluetooth-version-is-on-my-pc-f5d4cff7-c00d-337b-a642-d2d23b082793)) from Microsoft provides the list of LMP version match. Although it refers to the BT adapter itself, but it is still valid for the *remote connected device* (your keyboard):

```
LMP 12 – 2022 – Bluetooth 5.3
LMP 11 – 2020 – Bluetooth 5.2 (LE audio, AuraCast, LC3 codec)
LMP 10 – 2019 – Bluetooth 5.1 (AoA angle of arival)
LMP 9.x – 2016 – Bluetooth 5.0 (IoT and enhanced speeds)
LMP 8.x – 2014 – Bluetooth 4.2
LMP 7.x – 2013 – Bluetooth 4.1
LMP 6.x – 2010 – Bluetooth 4.0 (**subsets Classic, LE and HS**)
LMP 5.x – 2009 – Bluetooth 3.0 + HS
LMP 4.x – 2007 – Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
LMP 3.x – 2004 – Bluetooth 2.0 + EDR
LMP 2.x – 2003 – Bluetooth 1.2
LMP 1.x – 2002 – Bluetooth 1.1
LMP 0.x – 1999 – Bluetooth 1.0b
```

In order to check if your [keyboard HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Human_Interface_Device_Profile_(HID)) is a LE device (in BT 5), check [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1565738/how-to-check-the-bluetooth-capabilities-and-version) from SuperUser, but still it might be a classic device (in BT 5.0) and won't appear in that list.

I have not find yet any app which list the LMP parameter in Windows yet, neither in the logs (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1084256/how-can-i-see-a-list-of-recently-connected-bluetooth-devices)). Perhaps coding with the recent APIs could provide this info. As a side note, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550394/determine-bluetooth-version-for-a-specific-session) in StackOverflow mentioned that Android log does list this property directly.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 still didn't find any app to do that. I asked GPT4 for windows api, and it gave me the same answer that the driver shows the device information, however, which do not include bluetooth version of connected device. Maybe I'll check it on Android next time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).